# Button not working?

Tags: buttons

In my code `add_post_meta` is ignoring the button around it and is executing anyway. Why is this so?

I've tried the following:

```
<input type="submit" value="Test" id="submit">
    $thisid = wp_insert_post ( $post, true);
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if ( is_wp_error($thisid) ) {
            return get_error_codes();
            echo "not ok";
        }else{

            wp_insert_post($thisid);
            add_post_meta( $thisid, 'field_123123eee12312', $column2);
            echo "ok";
        }
    }
```

Added the two echo's and the echo `ok` is showing. No idea why this is so.

Also a request, can anyone add a tag for `add_post_meta` it seems get/update are there but not add.

Comment: What do you mean by 'ignoring the button around it'? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also note that if the meta key already exists `add_post_meta` will not update the value, nor add a new key, in which case `update_post_meta` may be the better choice (and is the once I always use).

Comment: I want it to happen when the submit actually happens, instead it now adds/updates it whenever I refresh the page not when clicking the button.

I used to use `update_post_meta` but I was advised to use `add_post_meta` for I have another question if you'd like to visit that. Because I already have a different problem running.

Comment: Do I need a form on wordpress in order to make this all work? That's the only thing I can make up `$_POST` wouldn't work.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you are trying to do. Are you on the front end? Are you creating a meta box? You need to provide some context if you want people to be able to answer... and a more descriptive title wouldn't hurt either. `update_post_meta()` will *add* the meta key if it doesn't exist.. so for me, there is almost no need for `add_post_meta()`.

Comment: Like I said I have another problem on which I use `update_post_meta` and that is on another question I've asked(That you can check out if you'd like it's unsolved) I there was advised to use `add_post_meta`, it's a bit to much to explain here. Anyway I have solved my issue as I answered it myself. All I wanted on this question was for it to work with a button and a button only and I have managed to do it.

Comment: "It to work"... You never described what "it" was so this question isn't likely to be helpful to anyone in the future.

Comment: In the question itself I stated "In my code add_post_meta is ignoring the button around it and is executing anyway" not to be rude but unless you didn't read my question it should've been clear enough that "it" would mean what I asked. That should be the reason why I received an answer and why I shouldn't be down voted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a major problems in your code :

1- you must use the `<form>` when you want to submit the data whatever the system you use (wordpress, EE ,php ,html ...).

2- if you want to check if the page submitted or just visited without submitted, you must change your condition to :

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
```

OR

```
if($_POST){
```

3- if you try to avoid the resend the Post data when you refresh the page after the submit process , you must add redirect code inside your condition.

4- move this `$thisid = wp_insert_post ( $post, true);` inside the condition ,so the post will be added just if there is a $_post data and remove `wp_insert_post($thisid);` from else statement.

4- about `add_post_meta` in your code you use wp_insert_post , so your code to add a new post then add a new meta to this post, so if you go to the new post and find the meta field this tell you `add_post_meta` is working.
note: you can add the same line twice to see if `add_post_meta` add two meta fields.

```
add_post_meta( $thisid, 'field_123123eee12312', $column2);
add_post_meta( $thisid, 'field_123123eee12312', $column2);
```

so you code will look something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">    
--- Your Fields -----
<input type="submit" value="Test" id="submit">
</form>
```

----------PHP Code---------

```
     if(!empty($_POST)){
       $thisid = wp_insert_post ( $post, true);
        if ( is_wp_error($thisid) ) {
            return get_error_codes();
            echo "not ok";
        }else{
            add_post_meta( $thisid, 'field_123123eee12312', $column2);
            echo "ok";
        }
    }
```

try it and let me know.

Regard's.

Comment: I found out about this all(Step 1,2 and 3) before this answer but I greatly appreciate it. Step 4 although I did not know of, thanks for the explanation. One side question though, you added the same meta key twice in Step 4, this is just an example right as normally they should both be different? Otherwise to me it seems like you're adding duplicate data.

Comment: yes this is just example the `add_post_meta` normal behavior is adding a new field even if it have the same key field_123123eee12312 , when you run this code you will see two meta field with the same key, this is just a test to check if `add_post_meta` works.

Comment: @AhmadSaad `wp_insert_post()` accepts an array of things (such as post title, post content, etc) and returns the new post's ID. `update_post_meta()`'s first parameter is an integer, therefore I don't think you can use the same `$thisid` for both.

Comment: yes  helgatheviking, this is right I don't notice this error in the first time I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was right, it was due to it not being in a form, I completely misperceived Wordpress.

Whatever you are using, ALWAYS add the following when you're using a submit:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Insert button here
</form>
```